# Tableau Desktop: How to add data labels to the box plot?

Tags: boxplot, tableau-api

I created a box plot in Tableau Desktop 8.1, but I couldn't figure out how to show data labels for median, 25% and 75%. I was able to show the min and max. Anyone know a solution that is not manual?

Thanks!

Comment: To get more responses, you may have to show a screen shot of what you have. Also, don't be afraid of manual solutions. In Tableau, many of the best functionality requires some playing around.

Answer (score 11):

1. After you create the box plot, right click on the y axis select "Add reference line, band or box."
2. Choose distribution.
3. Set the scope as per cell.
4. Choose Quartiles for the values
5. Choose Value for the label.
6. Choose "None" for the line.
7. Choose "No Fill" for the fill.
8. Hit the Apply or OK button.

Comment: Tableau has updated the settings box for this. Everything is the same except:  
Step 7: Fill:None and Step 8: Check 'Symmetric'